# How to calculate a bayes factor for unequal variances test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, bayesian

I'm curious whether there are any off the shelf methods (R, Python packages) that can generate a bayes factor for an unequal variances test.

Often times we use an F-test, Bartlett's test, Levine's test, or Brown-Forsythe, these are defaults in JMP, to test whether the variances of two populations are equal.  Which test is appropriate depends on how many groups, whether data is normal, etc.  These tests generate a test statistic and a p-value, and I'd like a nice way of calculating a Bayes factor instead of a p-value. I'd like to use a default, uniform prior, because generally I'm not sure how different the variances will be.